# Adding variables to array using a loop for DnD dice roller

Tags: java, arrays, loops

student here who is new to Java. I'm trying to make a fairly basic stat roller for DnD in android studio.
I have rolling and grabbing methods for particular sided dice down for thats fine.
I'm trying to loop the roll and add results from rolls to my array and then total them later.
This is what I have currently:

```
ArrayList<Integer> values = new ArrayList<Integer>();    

for (int counter = 0; counter < 4; counter++) {
    myDice = myDiceFactory.getDice("6");
    Integer value = myDice.diceRoll();
    values.add(value[counter]);
```

Getting `Array expected type; found: int` for `Values.add`
Would greatly appreciate anyone who point me in the right direction :)

Comment: what is Value[Counter] supposed to do? Value is not an array, so don't try to use it as one

Comment: What is your question? Post your complete code.

Comment: @Shriram the question is: he doesn't understand why he gets an 'Array expected type found: int' error

Comment: Change `Values.add(Value[Counter]);`  to `Values.add(Value);` . It will work

Comment: A side note, in Java variables follow a camelCase naming convention.

Comment: Apologies for the formatting and my use of 'counter' as it wasn't completed working code, it was just what I had at the time in the IDE. @Khalid Shah Thank you very much I feel a bit stupid now :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Value` is an Integer so do `Values.add(Value);`

You are treating the Integer object like an array. I'd recommend installing an IDE to help you with errors like this.

My IDE informs me that "Array type expected; found: java.lang.Integer'

Comment: Khalid Shah commented this also, thank you very much. I'm using Android Studio since I'm making a rather basic app to build to my phone.